# $\sum_{i=1}^n i2^i$

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

$\sum_{i=1}^n i2^i$

How can we derive a function out of this summation. I saw similar type  of [equation](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/30732/how-can-i-evaluate-sum-n-0-inftyn1xn) before but the $\lvert r\rvert$ in $ir^i$ is < 1. How can we create a function when $\lvert r\rvert > 1$ (in this case $2$)

Comment: In the title of the question you asked about $2^n$ instead of $2^i$. Which of both is correct? I assume $2^i$ because $2^n$ would be trivial.

Comment: The accepted answer to the question you linked to gives a formula for $S_{m}=\sum_{n=1}^{m}nr^{n}$ which is valid for any $r \ne 1$. It's only the final step (taking the limit) which requires $|r|<1$.

Comment: @MishaLavrov From the answer I linked, how did he get $S_{m} - rS_{m} = -mr^{m+1}+\sum_{n=1}^{m}r^{n}$

Comment: If you want to get rid of the $\sum$: I doubt that this is possible. Look at $r=10$ and $n<10$; in this case the results are numbers like 43210 or 876543210. I doubt that there is a possibility to write such numbers without the use of the $\sum$ sign.

Comment: Write $r S_m = \sum_{n=1}^{m+1}(n-1)r^n $ and subtract the two sums term-by-term.

Comment: http://www.ebyte.it/library/docs/math06b/PowerSeriesKpXk.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Using [differentiation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_calculus)**. From the well known identity 
$$1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^{n-1}+x^{n}=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1} \tag{1}$$
we have
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x^i=\frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}-1=\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1}$$
Now take the derivative 
$$\left(\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}x^i\right)^{'}=\left(\frac{x^{n+1}-x}{x-1}\right)^{'}$$
which is
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ix^{i-1}=\frac{n x^{n+1}-(1+n)x^n+1}{(x-1)^2}$$
and multiply both sides by $x$
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}ix^{i}=\frac{nx^{n+2}-(1+n)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2}\tag{2}$$
and set $x=2$
$$\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n}i2^{i}=n2^{n+2}-(1+n)2^{n+1}+2\tag{3}$$